# Docker, UFW and IP Tables

Tags: iptables, firewall, docker, ufw

first of all, i kind of new to docker / linux / ufw and stuff!

**What i´m doing:**

I´m creating a docker container which exposes a port. in this case its 8080. 
 The container behaves as expected.

Secondly i want to close down the server. Therefore i activate UFW and only allow 22, 80, 443.

I would have expected that i cannot access the myserver:8080, since the port is closed! 
I understand that docker uses the iptables todo 'stuff' regarding routing to it. As of now its sadly just 'stuff' to me.

So i created the json file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with this content:

```
{
        "iptables": true
}
```

with the intent to make sure that all my ports stay closed and UFW works as expected.

At first everything seemed to be working just fine until i noticed that my container cannot reach out anymore. It seems that it cannot resolve the dns.

So i get that i´m playing with stuff i dont fully understand currently.

**What i´m trying todo!**

I basicly want containers running, with closed ports. But the containers should be able to reach http/https api´s on the outside. How can i accomplish that?

Any help and support for my learning process is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

The standard port used by DNS is UDP 53, so you have to allow the output port 53 in udf

```
sudo udf allow out 53
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to expose the port 8080 and want to bind the same port on host for the container, then you need to open 8080 port on host Iptables. / ufw.

```
docker run -d --name container_name -p 8080:8080 Image_name:tag
```